# Hardhat connecting to localhost contract for tasks

Tags: solidity, javascript, hardhat

I am working on some hardhat tasks to automate the management of a smart contract. Here's a basic task for [granting roles](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/access#AccessControl-grantRole-bytes32-address-)

```
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-web3");

task("grantrole", "Grants <Role> to <Wallet>")
    .addParam("account", "The account's address")
    .addParam("role", "The Role to Grant")
    .setAction(async (taskArgs) => {
        let minterRole = ethers.utils.id("MINTER_ROLE");


        const account = web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(taskArgs.account);
        const MyContract = await ethers.getContractFactory("MyContract");
        const contract = await MyContract.attach(
            "0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3"
        );

        console.log(await contract.grantRole(minterRole, account));
});

module.exports = {}
```

A couple of problems here.

- Is there a way I can configure this to a specific contract for one environment vs another. I don't want to hardcode any contract addresses here.
- The method above does nothing. If I execute the following `npx hardhat grantrole --account 0xfabb0ac9d68b0b445fb7357272ff202c5651694a --role MINTER_ROLE` then I go into `npx hardhat console` to verify:

```
> await contract.hasRole(minterRole, "0xfabb0ac9d68b0b445fb7357272ff202c5651694a");
false
```

In fact, I don't see the RPC call to my local node ever get made.

So my questions are, how do I configure the task to call the right RPC/contract based on environment? (localhost vs prod)? and can I configure it so contracts aren't hard coded in the task?

Comment: I answered only the second question because I don't understand the first one. Also, you should try to make one question per post, I believe it's part of the rules of the site, and in any case it's a good practice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The method above does nothing. If I execute the following...

When you execute a task without passing any `--network`, that task is run in the in-process Hardhat network. This is an ephemeral network that is created and destroyed with the process. So when you run your task and then do `npx hardhat console`, the second command is using a new, fresh instance of the Hardhat network.

Instead, you should start a Hardhat node with `npx hardhat node` in one terminal to have a persistent instance of the network, and then in another terminal do `npx hardhat <your-task> --network localhost` and then `npx hardhat console --network localhost`.